# LED's emitting high pitched noise

Tags: lighting, led

I have some LED lights hooked up to a trophy cabinet and for some reason it's emitting a fairly loud high pitched noise, does anyone know what this could be?

Comment: Is it all of them or just one?  Most 120V LED bulbs have a power supply that converts the 120V AC to DC in the correct voltage for the LED itself.  The power supply is nearly always of the "switching" variety and the designer of the unit should have designed the switching frequency to be ABOVE the human hearing range.  In this case clearly there is a problem.  Either the unit is defective or they are just a poor design.

Comment: It is all of them, would you suggest replacing them instead of attempting to fix them?

Comment: As I said, is it ONE of them or ALL of them making the noise.  Generally these are not user-serviceable.  So your only real options are to live when them or replace them with some that don't make noise.  I have found that the cheap ones tend to be noisier than the higher quality ones.

Comment: are they dimmable? do they still make sound if driven at full brightness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible for an LED*  to emit noise (more than once).

This is a problem with the power supply or driver circuit.

If these are 120V screw-in LEDs, then the built-in driver is the problem and replacing the whole unit is hte only option.

If this is a "plug-n-play" LED conversion of a fluorescent tube, then the old fluorescent ballast is still in play, and that is surely the source of the noise.  It should be replaced with a ballast-bypass aka direct-wire LED, which will remove the ballast from the circuit altogether.

---

* If you think I mean the consumer products sold at Ikea and Walmart that replace incandescent bulbs, no. I make that clear later in my answer.  I mean LED *components*. Which is very relevant to trophy cabinets, because they are typically LED "strips" comprised of actual LEDs, and separate power supplies.

Answer (score 0):

mine were dimmed when they were making a high pitched ringing and so I put the brightness up and they didn't ring